# May installing/using .NET 4.0 full profile require elevated admin privileges?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, elevated-privileges, .net-client-profile, admin-rights

If we develop a traditional desktop WinForms app with the target framework set to '.NET 4.0 Client Profile' and would like to switch to the full .NET Framework profile, can it cause any issues which can be solved only by elevating the app rights? And what about the .NET 4.0 full profile installation process itself - - may it require admin rights? Our goal is to make possible the usage of our app by any user without admin rights.

Comment: No, Yes.  A user without admin rights can't get the Client profile installed either so there's no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally admin privilege is mandatory only if the application installation modifies any `system files` or `restricted registry` settings.

Windows installers require admin privilege as it writes some information into registry. Also any version of .NET Framework require admin privilege to install. But as you might know windows OS comes with .Net Framework(*Framework version vary with OS*).